# if statement with all combinations selectizeInput Shiny

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, flextable

I have a `list` of model tables based on all combinations of variables in a dataset. Depending on what variables are chosen in `selectizeInput` I want to return the associated model table in `Shiny`.

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
vars <- names(iris)[-1]
vars_comb <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)
model_formula <- lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(v, "Sepal.Length"))
#create models
models <- lapply(model_formula, function(x) glm(x, data = iris))
names(models) <- model_formula
#create list of tables (flextable)
model_coeff_ft <- map(models, function(x) data.frame(x$coefficients) %>% 
                        rownames_to_column("Variables") %>% 
                     flextable() %>% 
                     set_caption("Table 1: Coefficients"))
#return table e.g.
model_coeff_ft[[15]] 


#shiny:
variable_names <- c("Sepal width" = "Sepal.Width", "Petal length" = "Petal.Length", "Petal width" = "Petal.Width", "Species" =  "Species")
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Models"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("variables",
                     label = "Choose variable", choices = variable_names, multiple = TRUE, 
                     options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("dataset_flextable")
    )
  )
)
#I NEED TO PUT IF STATEMENT IN HERE:
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dataset_flextable <- renderUI({
    req(input$variables)
    get(input$variables) %>%
      htmltools_value()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

so for example, when all variables are chosen:

[image]

I want to return:

[image]

but when only say, two variables are chosen:

[image]

I want the associated table returned:

[image]

etc...

I think i need to include an `if statement` in the `server` function but I'm unsure how to do this. I was thinking something along the lines of the following but I'm not sure how to make this more flexible to include all combinations and also unsure how to include it in the `server` side.

```
#vars
# [1] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species" 
#grepl or str_detect - if all variables selected then print model_coeff_ft[[15]]
if (all(str_detect(names(model_coeff_ft)[[15]], vars)) == TRUE) {
  model_coeff_ft[[15]]
}
#but i really need to reference all combinations somehow
names(model_coeff_ft)
# [1] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width"                                        "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length"                                      
#  [3] "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width"                                        "Sepal.Length ~ Species"                                           
#  [5] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length"                         "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width"                         
#  [7] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species"                              "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width"                        
#  [9] "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Species"                             "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species"                             
# [11] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"           "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species"              
# [13] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width + Species"                "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species"              
# [15] "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species"
```

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first pass:

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)


#shiny:
variable_names <- c("Sepal width" = "Sepal.Width", "Petal length" = "Petal.Length", "Petal width" = "Petal.Width", "Species" =  "Species")
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Models"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("variables",
                           label = "Choose variable", choices = variable_names, multiple = TRUE, 
                           options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("dataset_flextable")
        )
    )
)
#I NEED TO PUT IF STATEMENT IN HERE:
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dataset_flextable <- renderUI({
        req(input$variables)
        vars <- input$variables
        vars_comb <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)
        model_formula <- lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(v, "Sepal.Length"))
        #create models
        models <- lapply(model_formula, function(x) glm(x, data = iris))
        names(models) <- model_formula
        #create list of tables (flextable)
        model_coeff_ft <- map(models, function(x) data.frame(x$coefficients) %>% 
                                  rownames_to_column("Variables") %>% 
                                  flextable() %>% 
                                  set_caption("Table 1: Coefficients"))
        #return table e.g.
        model_coeff_ft[[length(model_coeff_ft)]] %>% htmltools_value()
        
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I will try improve on it shortly.

**Update**

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)


#shiny:
variable_names <- c("Sepal width" = "Sepal.Width", "Petal length" = "Petal.Length", "Petal width" = "Petal.Width", "Species" =  "Species")
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Models"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("variables",
                           label = "Choose variable", choices = variable_names, multiple = TRUE, 
                           options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop'))),
            selectInput("model", "Choose model", choices = NULL)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("dataset_flextable")
        )
    )
)
#I NEED TO PUT IF STATEMENT IN HERE:
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    model_coeff_ft <- reactive({
        req(input$variables)
        vars <- input$variables
        vars_comb <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)
        model_formula <- lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(v, "Sepal.Length"))
        #create models
        models <- lapply(model_formula, function(x) glm(x, data = iris))
        names(models) <- model_formula
        #create list of tables (flextable)
        model_coeff_ft <- map(models, function(x) data.frame(x$coefficients) %>% 
                                  rownames_to_column("Variables") %>% 
                                  flextable() %>% 
                                  set_caption("Table 1: Coefficients"))
        updateSelectInput(session, "model", choices = names(model_coeff_ft), selected = last(names(model_coeff_ft)))
        return(model_coeff_ft)
    })
    
    
    
    output$dataset_flextable <- renderUI({
        req(model_coeff_ft(), input$model, input$model %in% names(model_coeff_ft()))
        
        #return table e.g.
        model_coeff_ft()[[input$model]] %>% htmltools_value()
        
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update 2** - based on comment below

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

vars <- names(iris)[-1] %>% sort()
vars_comb <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)
model_formula <- lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(v, "Sepal.Length"))
#create models
models <- lapply(model_formula, function(x) glm(x, data = iris))
names(models) <- model_formula
#create list of tables (flextable)
model_coeff_ft <- map(models, function(x) data.frame(x$coefficients) %>% 
                          rownames_to_column("Variables") %>% 
                          flextable() %>% 
                          set_caption("Table 1: Coefficients"))

#shiny:
variable_names <- sort(c("Sepal width" = "Sepal.Width", "Petal length" = "Petal.Length", "Petal width" = "Petal.Width", "Species" =  "Species"))
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Models"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("variables",
                           label = "Choose variable", choices = variable_names, multiple = TRUE, 
                           options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop'))),
            selectInput("model", "Choose model", choices = NULL)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("dataset_flextable")
        )
    )
)
#I NEED TO PUT IF STATEMENT IN HERE:
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$variables, {
        vars <- input$variables %>% sort()
        vars_comb <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(n) combn(vars, n, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)
        model_formula <- as.character(lapply(vars_comb, function(v) reformulate(v, "Sepal.Length")))
        
        updateSelectInput(session, "model", choices = model_formula, selected = last(model_formula))
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    
    
    output$dataset_flextable <- renderUI({
        req(input$model, input$model %in% names(model_coeff_ft))
        
        #return table e.g.
        model_coeff_ft[[input$model]] %>% htmltools_value()
        
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you, this works well but I dont want to include the model code within the `shiny` itself. The real models take a long time to run so I am going to have them "pre-run" and saved in a list so the list can be read in quickly when I open the app. Taking your second attempt, I essentially want to remove line 5 to 14 of your `server` code and read in a pre-saved list e.g. save `saveRDS(model_coeff_ft, "testlist.rds")` and read back in `model_coeff_ft <- readRDS("testlist.rds")` but this doesn't work. Would you know how to achieve this? I hope that makes sense!